# Can an anonymous user upload a file to aws s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm creating an application in asp.net that anonymous users can upload their files to and store it to AWS S3. Is this possible?

Comment: Technically yes, but I'm not sure its a wise decision. Maybe there is better way? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Would presigned-urls that are restricted to PUT work for your use-case? That would give you more controll than setting the whole bucket to public.

Comment: @Marcin i just wanted to create an application that users can add files to aws s3 and give them the link of the uploaded file. can you please explain why it's not a wise decision? im new to aws and i still have to learn a lot about it

Comment: If anonymous users start sharing copyrighted materials through your portal, you may have to do some explaining later on, for example.

Comment: @JOJO Please edit your question to include more information. For example, will users authenticate to your application before uploading? Once the files are uploaded, how will they be tracked/managed by your application? Will users be able to access/download the files that they uploaded? Should those files be private to the user that uploaded them, or should anyone be allowed to download them. Please update your question to provide as much information as possible, so we can suggest the most suitable method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make S3 bucket public. More informaion: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/block-public-access-bucket.html
However, it's not good to do so. Alternate ways can be given if business requirement is known.

Comment: does making the bucket public means that anonymous users will have access to all the files in the bucket?

Comment: You can restrict access to objects in the bucket and give permission to users to upload objects in the bucket.